# Spring: Override save method in CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I would like to add some code in save method in `CrudRepository` but keep orginal functionality. After that save method should do what before, save to repository but additionally execute extra action. Is it possible? If so, how could I do it properly?

Thank you in advance for any tips

Edit

So, I would like to create method like this:

```
@Override
public default <S extends MyClass> S save(S myClassItem) {
    //here my functionality 
    super.save(myClassItem); //from CrudRepository
    return myClassItem;
}
```

Comment: You have your own crudRepository right? Or is it from some jar?

Comment: Extend the CrudRepo, override your save method and then call super(args) on the parent repo....In a nutshell

Comment: Are you sure that code should co in the save method and not in the service method you are using? What do you want to add?

Comment: @Mechkov CrudRepository is an interface ... can you elaborate?

Comment: @M.Deinum i have similar issue ... i guess the point here is that rest repository is automatically exposed so there is no service method

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to user super in such a method (default and overridden). So you must change the name of the method - which might not be exactly what you are looking for :

```
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, String> {

    default MyClass mySave(MyClass myClassItem) {
        save(myClassItem);
        return myClassItem;
    }
}
```